# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Wired/Ethernet Internet Timeout - Not working

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I am connecting via Ethernet/Wired Internet and it is working fine too. However after few minutes the Internet does not work even connection was in connecting stage.

I disconnected and again connected, the Internet works well however again same issue reoccurs. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with dynamic IP allocation in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Please use the below code and it work fine:

```
sudo dhclient
```